# Prioritize cron jobs running simultaneously

Tags: laravel, cron, jobs, job-scheduling

I have these commands set on different time in which different crons are running.
now i want to prioritize the particular command whenever it runs.
for example

```
    $schedule->command(CronDelayMailCommand::class)->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command(QuickStartMailCommand::class)->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command(DailyMidnight::class)->daily()->timezone('America/New_York')->at('10:00');
    $schedule->command(WeeklyCron::class)->weekly()->fridays()->timezone('America/New_York')->at('23:59');
```

now i want to give more priority to WeeklyCron command (this should run first) on weekends and then CronDelayMailCommand or any other commands.

is it possible to prioritize the cron commands ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Queues.Work well
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.